# How to remove autofill highlight when field is updated programmatically?

Tags: css, google-chrome, aurelia, autofill

I am working on a form that is cleared programmatically when user submits it. I don't have any issue with chrome highlighting the fields that have been auto-filled. But the yellow background still remains after the form is submitted and the field is cleared. I could use following css-

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
```

But this permanently removes the highlight. I can set this css on form submit and remove it when the field is edited. But is there any better solution? I am working on Aurelia framework. I know the issue is not related to the framework but any framework specific workarounds are also fine.

Comment: add a class to do it upon edit? could be a simpel jquery onkeypress in the input event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the form to go back to the default state, you could use `.reset()`

```
var theForm = document.getElementById('theFormId');
theForm.reset();
```